# Looping through array and output as pairs (divider for each second element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

I have an array with anonymous elements. Elements are added to the array via php, like so:

```
$playlist = array();

while (databaseloop) {
  $playlist[] = $a_title;
  $playlist[] = $a_length;
}

echo json_encode(array('playlist'=>$playlist));
```

So the array becomes:

```
["Hello.mp3", "00:00:14", "Byebye.mp3", "00:00:30", "Whatsup.mp3", "00:00:07", "Goodnight.mp3", "00:00:19"] and so on
```

Then I retrieve this array in jquery with ajax post. All that works fine.

Now, I'm looking for a way to treat/output all array elements as pairs in javascript/jquery. "do something" for each second element. Like this:

```
foreach (two_elements_in_array) {
  // output track name
  // output track time
  // output some divider
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, maybe this is the most basic solution:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    var title = arr[i];
    var len = arr[i+1];
}
```

---

However, I would recommend you to arrange `$playlist` as follows:

```
while (databaseloop) {
    $playlist[] = array(
        "title" => $a_title,
        "length" => $a_length
    );
}
```

Then it will be easy to iterate the elements simply with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var title = arr[i]['title'];
    var len = arr[i]['length'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could split the array into an array of two-element arrays.

```
var arr = ["Hello.mp3", "00:00:14", "Byebye.mp3", "00:00:30", "Whatsup.mp3", "00:00:07", "Goodnight.mp3", "00:00:19"];
arr.map(function(elem,i,arr){return [elem, (i+1<arr.length) ? arr[i+1] : null];})
    .filter(function(elem,i){return !(i%2);});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
let pairs = playlist.reduce((list, _, index, source) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
        list.push(source.slice(index, index + 2));
    }
    return list;
}, []);
```

This gives you a 2-dimensional array `pairs` to work with.

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop with an increment of two.  You might want to make sure that your array length is long enough for i+1, in case the length isn't divisible by 2!

```
for (i = 0; i+1 < array.length; i+=2) {
  name = array[i];
  length = array[i+1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ["Hello.mp3", "00:00:14", "Byebye.mp3", "00:00:30", "Whatsup.mp3", "00:00:07", "Goodnight.mp3", "00:00:19"];

var group = [];
for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x += 2) {
    var track = arr[x],
        length = arr[x + 1];
    group.push({
       track: track,
       length: length
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as @VisioN said it would be easier if you use associative array or else you can have a separated array of labels while iterating on the client side

```
var d=["Hello.mp3", "00:00:14", "Byebye.mp3", "00:00:30", "Whatsup.mp3", "00:00:07", "Goodnight.mp3", "00:00:19"] ;
var e=["name","time"];
var c=0;
$.each(d,function(i,j){
    if(c>=2)c=0;
    console.log(e[c]+j);
    c++;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FmLYk/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you optimize your code a little bit more so that it would make a bit more sense and be less error prone, if that's possible that is.
This is also a great way to be more object-oriented!

Like this (I'm using jQuery here) :

```
var array = [ {name: "Hello.mp3", time: "00:00:14"}, {name: "Byebye.mp3", time:"00:00:30"}, {name: "Whatsup.mp3", time: "00:00:07"}, {name: "Goodnight.mp3", time: "00:00:19"}];
```

Then you would be able to loop over it and produce a bit more clean looking code

```
array.forEach(function(data){
    //edit the output here
    console.log(data.name + " " + data.time );  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Destructive, but clean:

```
while (arr.length) {
  const Title  = arr.shift();
  const Length = arr.shift();

  // Do work.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not with `foreach`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    var name = array[i];
    var time = array[i + 1];
    // do whatever
}
```

Comment: What does "not with foreach" mean?

Comment: It means that `foreach` is not the appropriate construct to use in this situation.